# SELECT as alias to another SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a relation "one to many".

So in table `person` I have id, name, etc and in table `tags` I have id, personid, tag

And one person can have *N* entries with different tags.

I thought I could do something like

```
SELECT id, name, 
    (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE personid = id) AS tags
    FROM person
```

And I expect to receive a result row with *NUMBER(id)*, *STRING(name)*, *ARRAY(tags)*.
I know how to do this with a for loop, with 2 separate queries but I think MySQL should be best to do this.

If I do a JOIN I end up with many rows, bu I want to group all tags in a array-like entry of each row I get, ie. one row per person.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT with GROUP BY id

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Something like this:

```
SELECT person.id, person.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM person 
    INNER JOIN tags ON tags.personid = person.id 
    GROUP BY person.id
```

Comment: You should use an alias for the tags field like `GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS tags`. Otherwise it would be difficult to acces that field on application side.